# how to have a turbine cluster for each eureka app in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, turbine

I am trying to obtain an "autoconfiguration" of turbine clusters from my eureka server.

registered on the eureka server I have configured 3 apps: app1, app2, app3. 
registered on the eureka server there are also a zuul proxy and a turbine monitor.

i can access the three apps via zuul correctly, i can see all of the hystrix.stream of each app correctly.

I have configured a single turbine cluster 'default' and I can see the merged turbine stream (and the dashboard) of all the three apps from the dashboard without issues.

my turbine application.properties looks like this:

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:33210/eureka/
turbine.app-config=app1,app2,app3
turbine.cluster-name-expression=new String("default")
```

what I can't seem to do is to distinguish the turbine streams to avoid mashing up all the hystrix commands between the three apps in the dashboard.

what I would like to have as a result is the possibility to put

```
/turbine.stream?cluster=app1
/turbine.stream?cluster=app2
/turbine.stream?cluster=app3
```

where cluster matches the eureka name of each app, and obtain three different dashboards. I thought by documentation that removing by the cluster-name-expression the default would be the appName instead of the static 'default', but it doesn't happen.

what did I get wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

property name should be like

```
turbine.clusterNameExpression= new String("default")
```

to have different cluster for each stream... assuming you even have different management port enabled on each service in eureka, i.e. 51511 and 51521 is for service endpoints and 51512 and 51522 is for management endpoints.

```
turbine.instanceInsertPort=false
turbine.appConfig=service1,service2
turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig=SERVICE1,SERVICE2
turbine.instanceUrlSuffix.SERVICE1=:51512/hystrix.stream
turbine.instanceUrlSuffix.SERVICE2=:51522/hystrix.stream
```

Comment: thank you for your time. i am using different ports so it's feasible, but is there any way to make this happen without having to specify the application suffixes one by one? something like what happens with zuul, that detects all applications and forwards them, each one with suffix equal to the application name,  unless a specific list is specified

Comment: I dont think so.. What zuul does is, it becomes a client of Eureka, and it talks to eureka for the list of applications registered in this registry server. I do not think turbine would be able to get it. Turbine is supposed to combine the Hystrix streams, and I do not think eureka knows about it.

Answer (score 0):

`turbine.clusterNameExpression= new String("default")`

this worked out for me.
I only replaced 
`turbine.cluster-name-expression='dafault'`
 with above and it worked like a miracle for me.